# Struts 2 dynamic URL patterns with dot

Tags: java, url, struts2, action-mapping

I tried to include dot `.` in a dynamic URL pattern in Struts 2 but it is not working

My Struts 2 configuration for dynamic URL is as follows

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />
<package name="api" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="api/v1/{sid}/function/{id}/version/{ver}" class="com.test.Main" method="test">
        <param name="sid">{sid}</param>
        <param name="id">{id}</param>
        <param name="ver">{ver}</param>
    </action>
</package>
```

if I give trigger a URL without any dot in URL then it is working

`/api/v1/test/function/1234/version/1`

but if I use it with dot as follows then it is giving 404

`/api/v1/test/function/1234/version/1.1`

Why is it not working? How to make it work?

Comment: I didn't use it myself butthe JavaDoc on `RegexPatternMatcher` says: "The regular expressions can be in the form {FIELD_NAME} or {FIELD_NAME:REGULAR_EXPRESSION}." - Thus you could try `{ver:\d+(\.\d+)?}`.

Comment: Good one. The dot in the last section is tricky because usually it is used to denote action extension. You can create your own `ActionMapper` to handle this or put something extra after the `/{ver}` part.

Comment: You can also create an improvement request - https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/WW.

Answer (score 0):

Dots `.` in URL means a file extension delimiter. While you are using data in the URL it should be encoded. The encoded value for the dot is `%2E`.

It's not Struts2 problem to use data with the parameters in the action name, but some characters if not properly encoded has special meaning. For detaild explanation of URL specification see [RFC 1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt).

> Reserved:
>
> Many URL schemes reserve certain characters for a special meaning: 
>   their appearance in the scheme-specific part of the URL has a
>   designated semantics. If the character corresponding to an octet is
>   reserved in a scheme, the octet must be encoded.  The characters ";", 
>   "/", "?", ":", "@", "=" and "&" are the characters which may be
>   reserved for special meaning within a scheme. No other characters may 
>   be reserved within a scheme.
>
> Usually a URL has the same interpretation when an octet is
>   represented by a character and when it encoded. However, this is not
>   true for reserved characters: encoding a character reserved for a
>   particular scheme may change the semantics of a URL.
>
> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>   reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>   unencoded within a URL.
>
> On the other hand, characters that are not required to be encoded
>   (including alphanumerics) may be encoded within the scheme-specific
>   part of a URL, as long as they are not being used for a reserved
>   purpose.